# Alternative To Conditional Panel In Shiny R

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-reactivity

I have an app where I would like to add different numbers of UiOutputs based on a number chosen by the user. Right now I am finding myself doing a ton of redundant conditional panels to create the outcome I am looking for. I was wondering if there is an easier way to produce the desired outcome through a function like "switch".

Here is the code using conditional Panels. The outcome is desirable. The amount of conditional panels and repetition is not.

I will only show with 2 conditional Panels but in my app I have 9. The app simply asks the users how many stocks they want to chose in their portfolio and the amount of shares for each stock.

```
library(shiny)

tickers = c("SPY", "IWM", "QQQ")

ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

    mainPanel(
        h3("lets test the corr Mat"),
        #inputs stock
        #inputs weight
       radioButtons("howMany", "How Many ETF's?", choices = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), selected = 1),
        actionButton("stest", "Stress Portfolio"),
       conditionalPanel("input.howMany == '1'", 
                        selectizeInput("stock1", "choseStock 1", choices = tickers, selected = "SPY"),
                        numericInput("weight1", "Choose Number of Shares 1", value = 100, min = 0, max = NA, step = 1)),
       conditionalPanel("input.howMany == '2'",
                        selectizeInput("stock1", "choseStock 1", choices = tickers, selected = "SPY"),
                        selectizeInput("stock2", "choseStock 2", choices = tickers, selected = "QQQ"),
                        numericInput("weight1", "Choose Number of Shares 1", value = 100, min = 0, max = NA, step = 1),
                        numericInput("weight2", "Choose Number of Shares 2", value = 100, min = 0, max = NA, step = 1))
    )


)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {



}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With my limited Shiny / R experience, I see two routes:  one in which you dynamically generate variable names, and one where you just pretty it up a bit.  I'm not confident I can do the former justice, so here's a way to do the latter:

```
tickers = c("SPY", "IWM", "QQQ")

ui <- fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

  mainPanel(
    h3("lets test the corr Mat"),
    radioButtons("howMany", "How Many ETF's?", choices = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), selected = 1),
    actionButton("stest", "Stress Portfolio"),

    fluidRow(
      column(width=6, selectizeInput("stock1", "choseStock 1", choices = tickers, selected = "SPY")),
      column(width=6, numericInput("weight1", "Choose Number of Shares 1", value = 100, min = 0, max = NA, step = 1))
  ),

# This is really all I had to offer
    conditionalPanel("input.howMany > 1",
                fluidRow(
                  column(width=6, selectizeInput("stock2", "choseStock 2", choices = tickers, selected = "QQQ")),
                  column(width=6, numericInput("weight2", "Choose Number of Shares 2", value = 100, min = 0, max = NA, step = 1))
                )
    )

  )

)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {



}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Line 17 calls out my two cents:  keep `stock1` and `weight1`, then change your `conditionalPanel` logic a bit to add in the new inputs.  With `fluidRow` and a pair of `column`s, successive variables have their own rows.

Extending this wouldn't be *much* cleaner, but at least each `conditionalPanel` would only have two new inputs and that would shorten your code a little